# Django3 :Unable to link html page in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-3.0

I've created new app as `register` and when trying to link in html its not redirecting page after link click

Project's `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'questions.apps.QuestionsConfig',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig', # registered new app
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

Project's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('questions.urls')),
    path('register/', include('register.urls')) #Linked apps urls.py
]
```

Register app's `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import RegisterForm

# Create your views here.
def register(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'form':form})
def test(request):
    return render(request,'test.html',{'form':form})
```

Register app's `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

When I use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register` in browser's url then it;s working fine.

**output in browser:**
[image]

But when I use `href` tag in html to render register.html page, I am getting error.

**when tried:**

```
<a href="#link" class="btn btn-info"  href="register/register">Register</a>
```

I'm not getting anything and in browser url it shows as

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/#link`

**when used :**

```
<a href="#link" class="btn btn-info"  href="{% url 'register/register' %}">Register</a>
```

getting error as:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'register/register' not found. 'register/register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `{% url %}` needs a view name. With that being said this line creating problems.

So replace this:

```html
<a href="#link" class="btn btn-info"  href="{% url 'register/register' %}">Register</a>
```

with:

```html
<a class="btn btn-info"  href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `href` in your anchor tag. You also have an error in your dynamic url. It should be as follows:

```
<a class="btn btn-info"  href="{% url 'register:register' %}">Register</a>
```

Also, in your project `urls.py`, it should be as follows:

```
path('register/', include('register.urls', namespace="register"))
```

Comment: Do I need to import somthing to to use namespace in project's `urls.py` because I am getting error as `TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'`

Comment: Sorry, I made an error. `namespace` should be inside the include function.